# Google Freebase Login using Google Client lib

Tags: c#, freebase, google-api-dotnet-client, google-authentication, mqlwrite

I am tring to write to Freebase using [MQLWrite](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mqlwrite).
I manage to write using the Freebase Query.
I enter the url and get an error saying

> Login is Required

I am using C#.

another thing to mention is I do not need a user consent. I created a service account in Google Developer console, and tried using the following code from this url:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Plus.ServiceAccount/Program.cs?repo=samples&r=406dd0081ca556a81621b910eac4445e3309ad1e&spec=svn.samples.406dd0081ca556a81621b910eac4445e3309ad1e

```
 public class Program
    {
        // A known public activity.
        private static String ACTIVITY_ID = "z12gtjhq3qn2xxl2o224exwiqruvtda0i";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plus API - Service Account");
            Console.WriteLine("==========================");

            String serviceAccountEmail = "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_HERE";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.
            var service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Plus API Sample",
            });

            Activity activity = service.Activities.Get(ACTIVITY_ID).Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("  Activity: " + activity.Object.Content);
            Console.WriteLine("  Video: " + activity.Object.Attachments[0].Url);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

1. I do not what ACTIVITY_ID means, is that the same as CLIENT_ID?
2. In the above example they use plus but i want to use Freebase and cannot find the scope property any where in the namespace.
   Appreciate any kind help... :)

Comment: are you using googles client lib? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Freebase.v1/  Can you post some code?

Comment: @DaImTo I added above the steps I took so far.. thank you :)

Comment: Is that returning authentication? Really would be easer with the client lib.

Comment: @DaImTo this is where I got so far, Appreciate the help :)

Comment: I am not sure that you can use a service account with Freebase I am still trying.  Documentation states you have to be authenticated yet it doesnt apear to work with the client lib.  Still playing with it

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you appreciate the help!!!! Do you know what ACTIVITY_ID means?

Comment: your example is using the Google+ API its not going to help you.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

[MQL Write](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mqlwrite) requires Authorization.  Make sure your authentication is working [correctly](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/how-tos/authorizing).

Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported.

Using MQL Write

> MQL Write supports legacy developer applications that write to
>   Freebase. In order to use MQL Write, developers must contact Freebase
>   and request additional quota using the [MQL Write Quota Access Request
>   form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/11jr_vvqKLtUSuLIIPTWkwsbDTTESucE3oHQa0IC9gBM/viewform?formkey=dGlRYW1VcUFKckNpU1U1VEhXRG02TVE6MQ#gid=0).

I have been able to get access with Public Access key only so far.

```
// Simple API example  
// Public API access = is from developer console its different then OAuth. (its at the bottom)

var service = new FreebaseService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "Discovery Sample",
                ApiKey = "{Public API access}",
            });
```

The Nuget package appears to be missing `Google.Apis.Auth` which is used for OAuth access. Either the API doesn't support Oauth access which cant be since the documentation states you need Oauth to access the write features.  Or there is something wrong with the NuGet package.

Can you try and run your write against this? See if it works or not.

Comment: if you are refering to the 'Public API access - APi key' I have tried using it in the url with simple http call, the same way I do when I use MQLRead, but it doesn't seem to be enough for MQLWrite. I couldn't use it in the code in my example because I do not have the 'scope' option.

Comment: I think scopes are part of Google.Apis.Auth which is why I think there may be something wrong with the nugget package for freebase.

Comment: I have some code some where that can seed stuff to APIs with out using the client Lib. I will try and find it and test with that.

Comment: I need to use MQLWrite and it requires login, I think it needs oAuth2. The Api Key is someting I use for MQLRead Quata.

Comment: did you request access? https://docs.google.com/forms/d/11jr_vvqKLtUSuLIIPTWkwsbDTTESucE3oHQa0IC9gBM/viewform?formkey=dGlRYW1VcUFKckNpU1U1VEhXRG02TVE6MQ#gid=0

Comment: @DaImTo This form is for requesting larger data quata, but I can't even load one item...  "The daily quota for loading data in freebase.com is 10k assertions/day.  This applies whether you're loading data using Freeq or the mqlwrite API. **Use this form to request more quota**."